# Cannot process transaction using PayPal module

Tags: python, paypal

I am trying to test Python and Paypal integration.

Here is my call to the PayPal module I got here: http://www.chickenwingsw.com/paypal-on-python

```
def testPayPal():
   import paypal
   PAYPAL_TEST_USERNAME = 'noeldo_1337351894_biz_api1.testacc.com'
   PAYPAL_TEST_PASSWORD = '1337353453'
   PAYPAL_TEST_SIGNATURE = 'AZ89-T17NMRVoILpOrfuXDv1jXZAlfJ0g5ZB76Rp5DNC010UYwxC2KS'
   PAYPAL_TEST_SIG_URL = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp'
   paypal.SKIP_AMT_VALIDATION = True
   pp = paypal.PayPal(PAYPAL_TEST_USERNAME, PAYPAL_TEST_PASSWORD, PAYPAL_TEST_SIGNATURE, PAYPAL_TEST_SIG_URL)

   rresp = pp.DoDirectPayment(paymentaction='Sale',
                             ipaddress='127.69.56.20',
                             creditcardtype='Visa',
                             acct='4188161369058553',
                             expdate=paypal.ShortDate(2017, 5),
                             cvv2='111',
                             salutation='Mr',
                             firstname='Homer',
                             middlename='J',
                             lastname='Simpson',
                             suffix='GSTEST',
                             street='742 Evergreen Terrace.',
                             city='San Jose',
                             state='CA',
                             countrycode='US',
                             zip='95131',
                             phonenum='123-456-7890',
                             shiptostreet='742 Evergreen Terrace.',
                             shiptocity='San Jose',
                             shiptostate='CA',
                             shiptozip='95131',
                             shiptocountrycode='US',
                             amt='100.00',
                             currencycode='USD')

   logging.info('testPayPal: got response %s' % resp)
```

I get an error when I run `print(testPayPal())`

> > PayPalException: ['The transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid address.']

I have setup my Paypal sandbox account using the account type Website Payments Pro.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 
Strange thing happened.

Was trying this on Friday and didn't work but came back to it on Monday and ta'da, it worked.

I set my sandbox account with paypal on friday so not sure if I needed to wait or if there was an issue with the sandbox environment.

Anyway, this code should work if anyone is looking for an example.

Cheers.

Comment: If this solved your issue, you should mark it as accepted. (It will let others know your problem is solved, and removes your question from the Unanswered queue).